# Unable to convert PostgreSQL text column to bytea

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

In my application I am using a postgresql database table with a "text" column to store
pickled python objects.
As database driver I'm using psycopg2 and until now I only passed python-strings (not unicode-objects) to the DB and retrieved strings from the DB. This basically worked fine until I recently decided to make String-handling the better/correct way and added the following construct to my DB-layer:

```
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODE)
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODEARRAY)
```

This basically works fine everywhere in my application and I'm using unicode-objects where possible now.

But for this special case with the text-column containing the pickled objects it makes troubles. I got it working in my test-system this way:

- retrieving the data: 
  `SELECT data::bytea, params FROM mytable`
- writing the data:
  `execute("UPDATE mytable SET data=%s", (psycopg2.Binary(cPickle.dumps(x)),) )`

... but unfortunately I'm getting errors with the SELECT for some columns in the production-system:

```
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for type bytea
```

This error also happens when I try to run the query in the psql shell.

Basically I'm planning to convert the column from "text" to "bytea", but the error
above also prevents me from doing this conversion.

As far as I can see, (when retrieving the column as pure python string) there are only characters with ord(c)<=127 in the string.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that casting `text` to `bytea` doesn't mean, take the bytes in the string and assemble them as a `bytea` value, but instead take the string and interpret it as an escaped input value to the `bytea` type.  So that won't work, mainly because pickle data contains lots of backslashes, which `bytea` interprets specially.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT convert_to(data, 'LATIN1') ...
```

This converts the string into a byte sequence (`bytea` value) in the LATIN1 encoding.  For you, the exact encoding doesn't matter, because it's all ASCII (but there is no `ASCII` encoding).

Comment: Your totally correct ... I did some further analysis in the meantime and also found out that only strings with backslashes have been affected (unfortunately I didn't have any of those in my test-data).
I managed to convert the data with `replace(column, '\', '\\')`, but your approach looks more elegant.

Comment: +1.  This worked for me with a nested functional call: encode(convert_to(concat(api_key.key,concat(':', api_key.shared_secret)),'LATIN1'),'base64')