# Attempts to alter a Postgresql column type from varchar to bytea hangs indefinitely

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

I've got a table with 4 rows in it in a non-production database used for development. There are 2 `varchar` columns that I want to convert to `bytea`. I don't care about the contents so I could of course drop the columns and then add them back, but I became confused when I tried to just change the type:

```
alter table whatever
  alter column col_1 set data type bytea using null,
  alter column col_2 set data type bytea using null;
```

When I try that, the `psql` client just hangs. By that I mean that it just sits there giving no feedback until I eventually hit `^C` and it aborts. I've tried that with a little test table and it works fine, but for some reason it doesn't work on the real table (which, really, is *also* just a "little test table").

The `using` clause doesn't seem to make a difference one way or the other; I can leave it out or give other values, and the command does the same thing.

I don't get an error, I just don't get anything. Is that what I should expect?

I'm on 9.1 on ubuntu 14.10 if it matters.

Comment: All the relevant column values are null, by the way, and they're not in any indexes.

Comment: Weird; I could alter the columns from `varchar` to `int` just fine, and then from `int` to `bytea` just fine after that.

Comment: What happens if you cast a `varchar` to `bytea`? Does it produce an error, a meaningful result, or what?

Comment: Check out `pg_stat_activity` and `pg_locks` when your query hangs (from a second SQL client). Most probably you have other transactions still referencing the table and your `alter table` is waiting for the exclusive lock.

Comment: How big is the underlying table? Do you have concurrent write load? To check for locks on the table: `SELECT * FROM pg_locks WHERE relation = whatever::regclass; ` More: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that kind-of makes sense; however why did it let me alter the type to `int`?  Well I guess I could have shut down the server that'd have the database open without thinking about it. Your explanation makes sense and is pleasing because it's not weird :)

Comment: Did you commit the change to type `int`? Maybe that's the transaction holding the lock.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no what I did was issue the command from `psql` and then wait. I tried several variations, and none worked. After I posted this question, I went back and tried doing `int` instead of `bytea`, and it worked. These were just command-line `psql -c` commands.

Comment: You may just have been lucky with `int` and no concurrent transactions interfered. I doubt you can reproduce the effect ..

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I agree and I'm in no way inclined to attempt it :) Thanks everybody; if you feel like typing in answers I'll upvote.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to convert PostgreSQL text column to bytea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300113/unable-to-convert-postgresql-text-column-to-bytea)

Answer (score 2):

> I don't care about the contents

In that case, this works on an empty table:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
    ALTER COLUMN colname TYPE bytea USING colname::bytea
;
```

Comment: This is incorrect -- you should use convert_to.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300113/unable-to-convert-postgresql-text-column-to-bytea .

Comment: @AndrewGaul From OP: _"I don't care about the contents"_. What I suggested worked for my case, and this is not incorrect. If you could provide a better answer, do it.

Comment: If you do not care about the contents then drop and re-add the column to make it obvious what you want.  The suggested answer mangles the data and is dangerous.  The linked SO answer correctly changes the column in place.

Comment: @ang once again it seems you only read part of sentences. _"This worked for me on [an] **empty** table".

Answer (score 1):

**Simple:**

Get the active locks from pg_locks:

```
select t.relname,l.locktype,page,virtualtransaction,pid,mode,granted from pg_locks l, pg_stat_all_tables t where l.relation=t.relid order by relation asc;
```

Copy the pid(ex: 14210) from above result and substitute in the below command.

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend('14210')
```