# Postgres lo_import large object import from other table text data

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I need to convert text data in a table to large object data in another table. So the table structure is :-

```
Employee->
id (character varying(130)),name (character varying(130)), description (text)

EmployeeDetailed ->
detailed_id(character varying(130)), desc_lob (oid)
```

What query can I run in order to transfer all the rows from Employee table to EmployeeDetailed table so that detailed_id would be populated from Employee's id columns and description would be converted to large object and oid would be inserted in desc_lob.

Can I use lo_import(), would it help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lo_import()` is a client interface command. You can use an `INSERT` statement, using the result of a `SELECT`, and use [lo_from_bytea](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/lo-funcs.html) inside that `SELECT` clause:

```sql
INSERT INTO EmployeeDetailed (detailed_id, desc_lob)
SELECT id, lo_from_bytea(0, convert_to(description, 'LATIN1'))
FROM Employee
```

Change `LATIN1` for whatever encoding you might like (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19305781/5015356))