# Equivalent of Oracle's utl_raw.cast_to_raw() in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle, function, casting

Does anybody know the postgres alternative to utl_raw.cast_to_raw() function?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to convert PostgreSQL text column to bytea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300113/unable-to-convert-postgresql-text-column-to-bytea). It is always better not to look for analogue, but try to solve the exact problem. Because ported code does not exploit all the power of used technology.

Answer (score 1):

Simply cast the string to `bytea`:

```
SELECT CAST('astring' AS bytea);
```